# How to associate nested relationships with attributes for a POST in JSON API

Tags: json-api

According to the [spec](http://jsonapi.org/format/#document-resource-identifier-objects), [resource identifier objects](http://jsonapi.org/format/#document-resource-identifier-objects) do not hold attributes.

I want to do a POST to create a new resource which includes other nested resource.
These are the basic resources: **club** (with *name*) and many **positions** (*type*). Think a football club with positions like goalkeeper, goalkeeper, striker, striker, etc.

When I do this association, I want to set some attributes like is the position required for this particular team. For example I only need 1 goalkeeper but I want to have a team with many reserve goalkeepers. When I model these entities in the DB I'll set the required attribute in a linkage table.

This is not compliant with JSON API:

```json
{
    "data": {
        "type": "club",
        "attributes": {
            "name": "Backyard Football Club"
        },
        "relationships": {
            "positions": {
                "data": [{
                        "id": "1",
                        "type": "position",
                        "attributes": {
                            "required": "true"
                        }
                    }, {
                        "id": "1",
                        "type": "position",
                        "attributes": {
                            "required": "false"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is also not valid:

```json
{
    "data": {
        "type": "club",
        "attributes": {
            "name": "Backyard Football Club",
            "positions": [{
                "position_id": "1",
                "required": "true"
            },
            {
                "position_id": "1",
                "required": "false"
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

So how is the best way to approach this association?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best approach here will be to create a separate resource for `club_position`

Creating a `club` will return a url to a create `club_positions`, you will then post `club_positions` to that url with a relationship identifier to the `position` and `club` resource.

Added benefit to this is that club_positions creation can be parallelized.